# How to change the default link in a list item

Tags: list, custom-list, list-item, default-value

I have a basic list and would like to customize the default link of the "Title" field. Currently when I click on the "Title" field of a list item it takes me to view that particular item; instead, I would like to change it so it takes me to a particuar site on the internet.

Is this possible? And if it is, is it possible without code changes?

Thanks for your help!

- Francisco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a code change, one thing you could do is add a URL field that does what you want, call it Title, and remove the Title field from views. The Title field would still show up in the Edit field if you do this, but it might be enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up doing. I couldn't set the new field's name to "Title" as it is a system field, but that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking at listing a bunch of website,document or file path links I would suggest the OOTB "Links" web part that sharepoint provides.

Comment: Anytime! I suggested this as Title is a system field and its unlikely that you will be able to create a duplicate of it.